# Breaking lists into subgroups in F#

Tags: f#

I'm starting to play with F# to do some data parsing and I was able to create a function to group an array of string into sub groups. The code looks like this:

```
let breakBy lines pattern =
    let rec breakByRec lines pattern acc = 
        match lines with 
        | [] -> acc
        | head::tail ->
            match pattern head with
            | true ->
                let newGroup = [head]
                let newList = newGroup :: acc
                breakByRec tail pattern newList
            | false ->
                let lastGroup = List.head acc                
                let newGroup = head :: lastGroup;
                let newList = newGroup :: List.tail acc
                breakByRec tail pattern newList
    breakByRec lines pattern [[]]
```

However, I feel that it could be improved specially regarding the way I handle intermediate values when concatenating the lists and the data structure used to return the grouped data.

The goal, at the end, is to insert each of these "groups" as single entities in the database. Is there a more suitable data structure that I should take a look?

Below is a sample ready to be used and an example output.

> ```
> let data = [
>     "Name=John"; "Age=29"; "City=San Francisco";
>     "Name=Jane"; "Age=28"; "City=New York";
>     "Name=Mike"; "Age=35"; "City=Miami"
> ]
>
> let matchName line = Regex.IsMatch(line, "^Name=")
> let people = breakBy data matchName
>
> printfn "%A" people
>
> /* 
> The output looks like this:
>
> val people : string list list = [
>    ["City=Miami"; "Age=35"; "Name=Mike"];
>    ["City=New York"; "Age=28"; "Name=Jane"];
>    ["City=San Francisco"; "Age=29"; "Name=John"]; 
>    []
> ]
> */
> ```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this would be better with one of the type providers - the CSV type provider is probably a close match here.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that a function named `breakBy` also reverses the order of the data violates the Principle of Least Surprise.  In my opinion, it's a bug.

`breakBy (Regex "^Name=").IsMatch` can be thought of as an transformation to be applied to a list.  Therefore, to facilitate currying, the order of the parameters to `breakBy` should be reversed, so that the predicate comes before the data.

Answer (score 2):

```
match pattern head with
| true -> …
| false -> …
```

I don't see any reason to use pattern matching here, `if` would work the same and is simpler:

```
if pattern head then …
else …
```

---

I think the empty group at the end of output shouldn't be there, get rid of it.

---

Since `lines` is a `list`, you can use `List.foldBack` to simplify the code:

```
let breakBy lines pattern =
    let processLine line (head, tail) =
        let head' = line::head
        if pattern line then
            ([], head'::tail)
        else
            (head', tail)
    snd <| List.foldBack processLine lines ([], [])
```

I'm assuming that the input always has to start with a matching line. If that's not necessarily true, the last line can't be just `snd`.

This also does not reverse the inputs, as 200_success suggested.